# Fix Animation with 'Add' Track Breaks the Animation

Tags: animation, armature, nla-editor

Firstly I had a model, and the issue was the pelvis was rotated the wrong way (in its default pose). To fix this, I rotated the pelvis back, then adjusted the rotation and location of the leg and lower spine bones back to their initial position (to compensate for the new location of the pelvis).

https://youtu.be/AMrEfKxOJ_U  (at the start, right is with the NLA fix track, left is without it but with a working animation)

I made this 'fix' into a 1-frame NLA track. In the video, you see that enabling this track fixes the glitching in the model and makes it look correct. However, playing the rest of the animation then just breaks it, throwing all the other rotations out of proportion.

None of the blending modes fix it. What do I do? I have more than a dozen models using this rig which need to be fixed and even more animations. How can I get it working?

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the bone roll?